# GridBagConstraints making buttons go center

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So , no matter what I change the gridx and gridy to, it does nothing. I used setBorderLayout and weightx and weighty, but nothing. Here is the code as of now:

```
package goatSoftware;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class CreateJFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public CreateJFrame(){
    super("Farm Calculator");

    JPanel a = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    final String user = System.getProperty("user.name");

    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setText("Add Doe");
    button.setVisible(true);

    JButton button2 = new JButton();
    button2.setText("Add Buck");
    button2.setVisible(true);

    gbc.gridx = 5;
    gbc.gridy = 5;
    a.add(button, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 4;
    gbc.gridy = 5;
    a.add(button2, gbc);
    a.setVisible(true);

    setSize(600,400);
    setLocation(400,200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    add(a);

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //Frame
            final JFrame newJFrame = new JFrame();
            //Panel2
            JPanel delta = new JPanel();
            //Panel3
            JPanel eta = new JPanel();
            //Panel
            JPanel alpha = new JPanel();
            //Area
            final JTextField beta = new JTextField();
            beta.setColumns(13);
            //Button
            JButton omega = new JButton();
            omega.setText("Submit");

            omega.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    try{

                        final File file = new File("/Users/"+user+"/config.plist");

                        // if file doesn't exists, then create it
                        if (!file.exists()) {
                            file.createNewFile();
                        }
                        FileWriter fileOut = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
                        String getInfo = beta.getText();
                        fileOut.write("\n<"+getInfo+">"+getInfo+"</"+getInfo+">");
                        fileOut.close();
                        newJFrame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(newJFrame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });

            beta.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    try{
                        final File file = new File("/Users/"+user+"/config.plist");

                        // if file doesn't exists, then create it
                        if (!file.exists()) {
                            file.createNewFile();
                        }
                        FileWriter fileOut = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
                        String getInfo = beta.getText();
                        fileOut.write("\n<"+getInfo+">"+getInfo+"</"+getInfo+">");
                        fileOut.close();
                        newJFrame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(newJFrame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
            //Field
            JTextArea gamma = new JTextArea();
            gamma.setText("Doe's name:");
            gamma.setEditable(false);

            alpha.add(beta);
            delta.add(gamma);
            delta.setVisible(true);
            alpha.setVisible(true);
            eta.setVisible(true);
            eta.add(omega);

            newJFrame.add(alpha, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            newJFrame.add(delta, BorderLayout.WEST);
            newJFrame.setSize(275, 125);
            newJFrame.setVisible(true);
            newJFrame.add(eta, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        }
    });

    button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //Frame
            final JFrame newJFrame = new JFrame();
            //Panel2
            JPanel delta = new JPanel();
            //Panel3
            JPanel eta = new JPanel();
            //Panel
            JPanel alpha = new JPanel();
            //Area
            final JTextField beta = new JTextField();
            beta.setColumns(13);
            //Button
            JButton omega = new JButton();
            omega.setText("Submit");

            omega.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    try{

                        final File file = new File("/Users/"+user+"/config.plist");

                        // if file doesn't exists, then create it
                        if (!file.exists()) {
                            file.createNewFile();
                        }
                        FileWriter fileOut = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
                        String getInfo = beta.getText();
                        fileOut.write("\n<buck><"+getInfo+">"+getInfo+"</"+getInfo+"></buck>");
                        fileOut.close();
                        newJFrame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(newJFrame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });

            beta.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    try{
                        final File file = new File("/Users/"+user+"/config.plist");

                        // if file doesn't exists, then create it
                        if (!file.exists()) {
                            file.createNewFile();
                        }
                        FileWriter fileOut = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
                        String getInfo = beta.getText();
                        fileOut.write("\n<buck><"+getInfo+">"+getInfo+"</"+getInfo+"></buck>");
                        fileOut.close();
                        newJFrame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(newJFrame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
            //Field
            JTextArea gamma = new JTextArea();
            gamma.setText("Buck's name:");
            gamma.setEditable(false);

            alpha.add(beta);
            delta.add(gamma);
            delta.setVisible(true);
            alpha.setVisible(true);
            eta.setVisible(true);
            eta.add(omega);

            newJFrame.add(alpha, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            newJFrame.add(delta, BorderLayout.WEST);
            newJFrame.setSize(275, 125);
            newJFrame.setVisible(true);
            newJFrame.add(eta, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        }
    });

}


//DON'T TOUCH THIS!!!! EVER!!!!
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

The buttons won't go to 5,5 and 5,4 where they are supposed to be.

Thanks!

!Thomas

Comment: What do 5,5 and 5,4 mean? A grid 5x5 implies 25 components. Your panel only has 2 components. What are you really trying to do? Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. Your question is about component layout. All the ActionListener code is completely unrelated to the question and it NOT required for the SSCCE.

Comment: sorry, but I couldn't just cut out like half the code. I watched a ton of videos and GridBagConstraints. I thought that 5,5 and 5,4 were coordinates on the JFrame, am I wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to have the Y axis change or the X axis? Your code varies the X not the Y, but your note above implies you want them to vary on the Y axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought that 5,5 and 5,4 were coordinates on the JFrame, am I wrong?

They are grid positions on the panel (not the frame), `ASSUMING` you have 25 components on the panel. You only have two components, so saying the component goes in the 5th row and 5th column makes no sense.

If you are just trying to display two components centered at the top of the frame then try:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER) );
panel.add(button1);
panel.add(button2);
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: I'm going to edit the question, because I have another one and don't want to make another thread.

Comment: @Nitroman, don't modify the context of a question. Nobody will answer is because 1) the original question has already been answer, 2) You still haven't prosted a proper `SSCCE`. The code you posted can NOT be compiled or executed. Get rid of all the setVisible() statements. Components (except top level containers) are visible by default.